# CSS3 Media Queries with css3 tabs

Tags: html, css, media-queries

![enter image description here][1]Essentially, i have created some nice tabs in ccs3 with radio buttons. Which looks fantastic in the browser and works a treat.

However this isn't the case on a mobile device, the text overflows out of the tabs pretty little container. The media queries in place don't seem to be doing anything, Any ideas  on how to get this working?

```
.tabs {
    position: relative;   
    min-height: 260px; /* Changes the height of the tabs section, enables you to change it for your text */
    clear: both;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px)  {
    .tabs {
        min-height: 480px; /* Changes the height of the tabs section (MOBILE), enables you to change it for your text */
    }
}
```

So what i'm trying to do is simply get a media query working so that i can change the height of the containing tab, so that the text in the container.

http://mdixon94.co.uk/HTML/elements.html

you can see here, that the tabs section if you scroll down looks fine, however if you preview it in say an iphone the text goes everywhere and i simply want to make the container bigger with a media query.

Comment: On which mobile device are you testing? Which version? Which browser? and Landscape or portrait orientation?

Comment: Portrait & Landscape don't work on an iPhone and all browsers all i want to do is make the height bigger, but its as if the media query isn't working! 480px is perfect for the iphone i just cant't get the query to actually make the change.

Comment: When designing for mobile you should stay away from pixel sizes. They are not very flexible or responsive, try using `%` or `em`.

Comment: Not pertaining to your question, I recommend adding: `-webkit-transition: .6s ease;
-moz-transition: .6s ease;
-ms-transition: .6s ease;
-o-transition: .6s ease;` to the `.priceblock`, it will look really nice I promise. :]

Answer (score 0):

You can use ellipsis in CSS

```
.tabs {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

which should give you something like this:

**Desktop**
|This is my tab text|
**Mobile**
|This is my...|

Answer (score 0):

You also can add this property:

```
.tabs {
   white-space:normal;
}
```

Comment: I'm simply trying to get the media query to work so that i can change the height of the containing tab...

Comment: Amm ok usually the width devices is 320px to 480px but what i see in your page is that you have fixed widths for each of the td's so that's gonna be a problem